# Ffmpeg - How to deinterlace a wrong interlacing?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, deinterlace

I have a source video that apparently has been interlaced a wrong way. The problem is: "ffmpeg -vf yadif=3:0" works perfectly in terms of time axis (results in a smooth motion overall), but it looks like every couple of scanlines are upside down in each frame.

So, I am looking for a way to swap the vertical positioning of top/bottom fields, keeping the temporal order unchanged, before applying a deinterlacer.

Before reaching the above assumption I have tried things like: "-vf 'yadif=3:0,crop=720:480:0:if(mod(n\,2)\,0\,2)'", but that didn't seem particularly helpful.

Any idea? (I am afraid I can't share a sample footage with you.)

Comment: See the il filter - https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#il

Comment: @Gyan, your suggestion points me to the right track! It seems "il=ls=1:cs=1:as=1" will be a good starting point for my goal, and maybe I can make use of the other options (l/c/a) for fine tuning, too. Thank you!